# Pattern for creating objects and set their common base and specific derived class properties

Tags: c#

I have a scenario to design a class structure to creates different types of derived class objects and set some of their common base class properties. Here is the final pattern I came up with to solve the problem. Can someone please take a look and advise if this a good design or can it be improved?

The domain model's `ContractEmployee` and `FullTimeEmployee` inherits from the base class `Employee`. The two properties of the base class `DailyWorkHours` and `WeeklyHolidays` will always have the same values for every `Employee`  sub type.

The employee objects needs to be created using their respective `Builder` classes such as a `ContractEmployeeBuilder` or `FullTimeEmployeeBuilder`. These builder classes are exposed to the client using interfaces.

The `Builder` classes are responsible for creating the respective employee objects, set their properties as well as their base class properties. **However I do not want every concrete builder class to to have the repeated code of creating the objects and setting the base class properties. So I have created a base class named `EmployeeBuilderBase` to achieve this.**

The abstract `EmployeeBuilderBase` class can create the object, set common base class properties and calls an abstract method named `SetProperties`. The builder classes can override this method to perform any additional operations they want to do on the object.

```
/***Code Below*****/
using System;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;

namespace EmployeeApp.Tests
{
    [TestClass]
    public class EmployeeBuilderTests
    {
        [TestMethod]
        public void CreateContractEmployee_ReturnsAContractEmployeeObject()
        {
            IContractEmployeeBuilder contractemployeeBuilder = new ContractEmployeeBuilder();
            ContractEmployee emp = contractemployeeBuilder.CreateContractEmployee(12, "ABC ltd.");
            Assert.AreEqual(emp.ContractDurationInMonths, 12);
            Assert.AreEqual(emp.DailyWorkHours, 8);
        }

        [TestMethod]
        public void CreateFullTimeEmployee_ReturnsAFullTimeEmployeeObject()
        {
            IFullTimeEmployeeBuilder fulltimeEmployeeBuilder = new FullTimeEmployeeBuilder();
            FullTimeEmployee emp = fulltimeEmployeeBuilder.CreateFullTimeEmployee("John Smith", 2500);
            Assert.AreEqual(emp.MonthlySalary, 2500);
            Assert.AreEqual(emp.DailyWorkHours, 8);
        }
    }

    ///*************************Domain Models*********************************************    
    public class Employee
    {
        public int DailyWorkHours { get; set; }
        public int WeeklyHolidays { get; set; }
    }

    public class ContractEmployee : Employee
    {
        public int ContractDurationInMonths { get; set; }
        public string AgencyName { get; set; }
    }

    public class FullTimeEmployee : Employee
    {
        public int MonthlySalary { get; set; }
        public string EmployeeName { get; set; }
    }

    ///*************************Interfaces and Abstract base class for the Builder Classes*********************************************    
    public interface IContractEmployeeBuilder
    {
        ContractEmployee CreateContractEmployee(int contractDurationInMonths, string agencyName);
    }

    public interface IFullTimeEmployeeBuilder
    {
        FullTimeEmployee CreateFullTimeEmployee(string employeeName, int monthlySalary);
    }

    public abstract class EmployeeBuilderBase<T> where T : Employee, new()
    {
        public T BuildEmployee(object options)
        {
            T obj = new T();
            obj.DailyWorkHours = 8;
            obj.WeeklyHolidays = 2;
            SetProperties(obj, options);
            return obj;
        }

        public abstract void SetProperties(T obj, object options);
    }

    //********Concrete Builder Classes***********************************
    public class ContractEmployeeBuilder : EmployeeBuilderBase<ContractEmployee>, IContractEmployeeBuilder
    {
        public ContractEmployee CreateContractEmployee(int contractDurationInMonths, string agencyName)
        {
            ContractEmployee contractor =
                BuildEmployee(new {ContractDurationInMonths = contractDurationInMonths, AgencyName = agencyName});
            return contractor;
        }

        public override void SetProperties(ContractEmployee obj, object options)
        {
            obj.ContractDurationInMonths = options.GetPropertyValue<int>("ContractDurationInMonths");
            obj.AgencyName = options.GetPropertyValue<string>("AgencyName");
        }
    }

    public class FullTimeEmployeeBuilder : EmployeeBuilderBase<FullTimeEmployee>, IFullTimeEmployeeBuilder
    {
        public FullTimeEmployee CreateFullTimeEmployee(string employeeName, int monthlySalary)
        {
            FullTimeEmployee emp = BuildEmployee(new {EmployeeName = employeeName, MonthlySalary = monthlySalary});
            return emp;
        }

        public override void SetProperties(FullTimeEmployee obj, object options)
        {
            obj.MonthlySalary = options.GetPropertyValue<int>("MonthlySalary");
            obj.EmployeeName = options.GetPropertyValue<string>("EmployeeName");
        }
    }

    //**** Object Extension method******
    public static class ObjectExtensions
    {
        public static T GetPropertyValue<T>(this object obj, string propName)
        {
            object value = obj.GetType().GetProperty(propName).GetValue(obj, null);
            return (T) value;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to CR. Your code is broken: 1) It doesn't compile (`GetValue` has no overload that accepts only one parameter). 2) Your example will fail at runtime in `SetProperties` because you're using the wrong property names - this coincidentally points out one of the biggest flaws in your approach. In any case we generally don't review broken code.

Comment: @ChrisWue - .Net 4.5 introduced a `GetValue` overload with only a single parameter.

Comment: Thank you.  I have corrected the code. Please take a look now.

Comment: @RobH: Yea, my fault. For some reason my test project was targeting 3.5

Comment: @ChrisWue I have corrected the code. Please take a look if you get a chance.

Answer (score 3):

`ContractDuration` has no point of reference.  Example: "6 months" from when?  My suggestion would be to include a DateTime for the contract effective date, and then perhaps change the `ContractDuration` to be a TimeSpan.

Comment: thank you. forget about datatypes. I just wrote this code to illustrate the scenareo . what I am interested in is to see if anyone can suggest me a better design pattern for this problem.